# SQl server Exception in Liquibase-update ,While creating table with column type varchar(2147483647)

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

Using Liquibase 3.1.1,I am trying to migrate Db scripts between any two SQl server Databases dynamically.

I am using Diff and update command of Liquibase.It is working working well with Db,which doesnot uses varchar(max) column.
For DB using varchar(max) column,liquibase uses VARCHAR(2147483647) for varchar(max),while creating changelog,and when it updates the target db,the below sql server exception is thrown.

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE [ASSET_ATTRIBUTE] ([ASSET_ATTR_ID] BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, [ASSET_GUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, [APP_ID] VARCHAR(30), [ATTR_TYPE] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, [ATTR_NAME] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, **[ATTR_VALUE_STRING] VARCHAR(2147483647)**, [ATTR_VALUE_DATE] datetime, CONSTRAINT [PK_ASSET_ATTRIBUTE] PRIMARY KEY ([ASSET_ATTR_ID])): The size (2147483647) given to the column 'ATTR_VALUE_STRING' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:61)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:106)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1189)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1172)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:352)
    ... 4 more

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The size (2147483647) given to the column 'ATTR_VALUE_STRING' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792) and some more
```

Even though its an sql server exception,i need to fix it through liquibase.
Is there any fix for this?
Why liquibase is not storing the column type as varchar(max),instead of varchar(2147483647),so that during update it wont throw the exception.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's somewhat related to the driver because it sends the 2147483647 as the "length" definition of those columns. Unless the Liquibase code is changed to detect that, I don't think there is much you can do (apart from doing a search & replace in the generated changelog file)

Comment: Probably because sql reports a `*VARCHAR(MAX)` column as Length -1, hence 2147483647

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for your reply.As you mentioned,i can try for search & replace in the generated changelog file.

Comment: @StuartLC ya i agree with it.Do you have idea of resolving it through liquibase or any liquibase extensions,available with the fix?

Comment: It is a problem with the driver returning back the size as 2147483647.  Liquibase handles it correctly for nvarchar but not varchar. I created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1743 to fix the issue.